# Any static analysis tools that help detect CPU endian issues?

Tags: static-analysis, endianness

Our team has managed a code base on an embedded big endian CPU for many years (10+).
We have generally not bothered to consider endian issues during this development and maintenance of this embedded code.

Soon, we will be moving this code base from a big endian CPU to a little endian CPU.

We are curious if anyone has experience with any particular static analysis or other tools to help with this transition.  We did find this useful whitepaper from Intel to help us get started:

http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/papers/endian.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you want to detect any aliased variables of different size (e.g., "char" aliased/union over "int", etc), pointer casts across different size types, and any functions that read or write external binary streams?

Comment: Yes, now that I've read the Intel paper... yes... those are certainly items we would be looking for.

Comment: Matches the Carl Ek article mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Sadly, the link to the Intel paper is dead.  I found it useful when last I looked at it but I can't get there any more.

Answer (score 3):

A colleague at Code Integrity Solutions, Carl Ek, recently wrote an article “Detecting Endian Issues with Static Analysis Tools” for Dr Dobbs: http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/226000073.

Comment: In Carl's article, I saw discussion of endianess checks, but I didn't see any specific static analysis tool that was configured to run those checks.  Did Carl use a specific tool? Can it be named? (Say hello to Carl from Ira, I know him from EA).

Comment: Yes and I’m not sure; I’ve asked Carl privately.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed I didn't mention any specific tools in my article. It was meant to give the reader some thoughts about how to approach the problem.  The general rules in the Intel paper are good, however, they are very generic, and thus can miss a lot of specific things that could be enforced in custom-checks for an individual customer's codebase and coding standard rules. Those checks in the Intel paper can be (mostly) implemented in Coverity's Static Analysis SDK and Klocwork's Checker Studio. I'm sure that [Semantic Designs' DMS](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html)  would be extremely effective in this detection as well :).  Having extensibility to a static analysis tool is very important: the coding issues can be very subtle and any canned out-of-the-box detection could potentially be very noisy. Having a flow/path-sensitive analysis is also desirable, as endian processing can/is often protected with guards/conditionals based on (possibly) statically analyzable/detectable conditions.  --carl

Comment: thanks.  We have some access to Coverity SQS through our corporate parent, I'll have to see what they can do for us... thank you!

Comment: Does the Coverity tool provide flow sensitive analysis? Intraprocedural? Interprocedural?

Answer (score 1):

Klocwork has introduced Endian analysis in its latest release (disclosure: I work there). Full inter-procedural analysis to ensure transformation points exist when sending/receiving from/to network or host. Technical whitepaper here that explains it in some more detail.

http://www.klocwork.com/resources/endian-deadlock-multicore-challenges/

Good luck! -Brendan